# FPDF - generated PDF is not displayed properly in browser

Tags: php, firefox, pdf, fpdf

I am generating a PDF document with a **FPDF** library.
I am trying to display a generated document in browser (*Firefox, Chrome, Opera*) but all i get are strange characters starting with:

```
%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <>...
```

This is my code. I am trying to add two images to the document.

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('./image.png',10,10,0,0,'png');
$pdf->Image('./image.png',10,120,0,0,'png');
$pdf->Output('file.pdf','I');
```

If I use the output with the 'D' option:

```
$pdf->Output('file.pdf','D');
```

and save the file on the disc, the pdf document is fine.

Comment: Accept answers to your questions!

Comment: To accept questions I need a minimum reputation of 15

Comment: Not upvote, accept! Click the tick next to the correct answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need to add the correct content type header. When the web server serves up a file, it tries to give the correct content type header it guesses from the file, but here, as you're generating it with PHP, the default header will be sent, which is usually text/html. Try adding this to the start of your code:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

And it should send with the correct content type header.

Comment: The FPDF Output function is already setting headers as follows:
`header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');`

Comment: Have you looked at the returned headers in an inspector (Firefox and Chrome have built in tools to do this) as it may be that those headers are not being output by default? It always helps to check just to be sure that the headers you expect are actually there.

Answer (score 8):

I run into the same problem and I add `ob_get_clean();` before `$pdf->OutPut()` and I got the correct result.

It was because the header was not correct, but even I set the header before outputting the pdf, it still not correct.

Comment: This helped me - it removes any stray headers or other content that your code may be outputting and lets FPDF get on with serving the PDF.

Answer (score 3):

change D to I

```
$pdf->Output('file.pdf','I');
```

send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if available. The name given by name is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.

from there documentation
[fpdf documentaion](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm)

Comment: This worked for me and solved the problem that has taken me several days to get round. Thank you so much!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add exit as follows :

```
$pdf->Output();
exit;
```

[Reference](https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/188158/pdf-and-http-headers)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ob_start (); //used before output.
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i should put it as a comment or answer, i had same issue on my localhost, but once i placed my code on live server the issue resolved automatically. Try cleaning all cookies on your local system and it may help too.

Answer (score 0):

I had applied all the above options with different sequences and this is how finally it works. Thanks

```
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $custom_data);
$final = html_entity_decode($str ,ENT_QUOTES, 'windows-1252');
$pdf = new FPDF();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Courier','',16);
$pdf->MultiCell(190, '10', $final, '', 'L');
ob_get_clean();
$pdf->Output($afterDash.".pdf", "I");
exit;
```